# Setting Integer Value in Table View Controller (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) For Use With PList (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm attempting to use a PList to populate a view controller that's pushed from a view controller that's pushed from a table view. More simply:

TableViewController-->DetailViewController-->2ndDetailViewController(<-This one is the one I'm populating)

The way I'm attempting to do this is by setting an integer to a value when the user clicks on the row in the Table View. I will then use the value of that integer to point to the right value in the PList and pull out the corresponding string. In the second View Controller, I'm trying to populate a UIImageView with an image from the PList. Here's the code of my didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     DealsDetailViewController *dealsDetail = [[DealsDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DealsDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
     dealsDetail.dealsImageString = [[self.dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"];
     dealsDetail.dealsLabelString = [[self.dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
     dealsDetail.title = [[self.dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];     

if ([[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Deal #1"]) {
    dealsDetail.dealsInt = 0;
    [dealsDetail setTitle:[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

if ([[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Deal #2"]) {
    dealsDetail.dealsInt = 1;
    [dealsDetail setTitle:[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

if ([[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Deal #3"]) {
    dealsDetail.dealsInt = 2;
    [dealsDetail setTitle:[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:dealsDetail animated:YES];
[dealsDetail release];
```

Everything gets populated correctly. I've attempted to NSLog the value of dealsDetail.dealsInt in both the table view controller (on clicking the button) and in the viewDidLoad method of the DealsDetailViewController. Both times, it returns a value of '0' no matter which row I click. Where have I gone wrong in my syntax?

EDIT--------
Here's what I get when I log out:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);


2011-11-28 17:40:59.092 Stores Tab Bar[7386:207] {
    Barcode = "SampleBarCode3.png";
    Description = "Here's the deal 3";
    Image = "FritoTest.png";
    Name = "Deal #3";
    Thumbnail = "dollars.png";
}
```

It logs out the PList contents of the object that's clicked correctly. So it's grabbing the right information (which I presumed it was since it was populating the table view and the detail view correctly...)

Comment: This code looks fine. Please include the declaration of the property from DealsDetailViewController and the code where you use this value when picking the image - it sounds like you may have an error in your string formatting so the logging / filename isn't working correctly

Comment: I haven't actually written the code yet to set the image in the second DealsDetailViewController since it was appearing that the integer wasn't holding the value yet (I wanted to make sure that this was working first). Would there be a reason why it would always log '0' no matter which button I pressed?

Comment: Are you having trouble with DetailViewConroller or the SecondDetailViewController or both? Your question starts with the second one and then seems to move to the first?

Comment: I haven't yet approached the SecondDetaiViewController at all since I want to set that integer first knowing that I can later recall it. jrturton's answer below is more on the right track, I basically just want to be able to NSLog out the different values of the integers when I click on the corresponding rows and then I'll go from there. So I'm just looking to log it correctly right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ([[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Deal #1"]) {
    dealsDetail.dealsInt = 0;
    [dealsDetail setTitle:[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

This seems to contradict your earlier use of the object within `dealsArray`. It looks like a dictionary in the lines above:

```
dealsDetail.dealsImageString = [[self.dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"];
```

And yet here you are comparing it to a static string. What is happening is that it isn't matching any of these if conditions and so is remaining at zero.

You want the following:

```
if ([[[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"] isEqualToString:@"Deal #1"]) {
```

Note I am taking another objectForKey (key being @"Name" as per your edit above) from the dictionary, and I am also using `isEqualToString:` which is the correct way of comparing strings.

Comment: Ok, yeah I see exactly what you're saying. I've been struggling with grasping the coding differences when using a Plist with an array as opposed to a dictionary etc. I've tried what you put (which makes total sense to me), but it's still returning '0'. Would a snippet of the source code from my PList help at all?

Comment: More useful would be NSLog(@"%@",[dealsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

Comment: I just added an edit above with what it logged out which is the correct information for the third row pressed (the other two row worked too). It's grabbing the information and understanding which row is being pressed but not changing the integer value...

Comment: Updated answer. It is a dictionary, you need to use objectForKey and isEqualToString as I originally guessed.

Comment: I'm still not getting why the integer value is not changing (or why it isn't being printed out)...

Comment: Perhaps there's a simpler way to accomplish what I'm going for then?

Comment: Have you made the change I suggest? The reason your current code isn't doing anything is that none of the if statements are ever true, so the int value is never set to anything and remains at zero.